# How to download first line of xlsx file via url python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-requests, xlsx

I used to use `requests` lib to load single line via url:

```
import requests

def get_line(url):
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    for line in resp.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
        yield line

line = get_line(url)
print(next(line))
```

A text files loading perfectly. But if I want to load .xlsx, result looks like unprintable symbols:

```
PK [symbols] [Content_Types].xml [symbols]
```

Is there a way to load single row of cells?

Comment: what kind of data do you want to receive? first row of excel sheet?

Comment: yes. May be not first but line by line. I want to get new line only.

Comment: XSLX files do not consist of "lines of text".

Comment: The "PK" header tells us that you're working with a zipped file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just read raw `HTTP` response and seek for the particular Excel data. In order to get `xlsx` file contents in proper format you need to use an appropriate library.

One of the common libraries is `xlrd`, you can install it with `pip`:

```
sudo pip3 install xlrd
```

Example:

```
import requests
import xlrd

example_url = 'http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/excel-files/fibonacci-sequence.xlsx'
r = requests.get(example_url)  # make an HTTP request

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=r.content)  # open workbook
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)  # get first sheet
first_row = worksheet.row(0)  # you can iterate over rows of a worksheet as well

print(first_row)  # list of cells
```

xlrd [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

---

If you want to be able to read your data line by line - you should switch to more simple data representation format, like **.csv** or simple text files.

Comment: Thank you. It`s work! But is there a way to load not full document?

Comment: Since `.xlsx` is not a regular text file - you can't do that. You can't read it line by line. You need to download the full file before you can get data out of it.